# Use windows or linux to start work with Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm new to Ruby On Rails and I want to know which is better to use for work with it. Windows or Linux. I've never worked with Linux before but I heard It's better to work with it. Is it necessary for someone like me to install linux or I can use windows and the results will be same with linux?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your current dev machine is running Windows, and you don't have access to a Linux environment right now, don't let that stop you from getting started with Rails. *Definitely*, *definitely*, *definitely* install the DevKit first thing (if it's not included in RubyInstaller yet). See https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit for that.

If you get deep into Rails development, or even start doing it for a living, you will inevitably drift towards using Linux on your dev machine. The problem is not Rails, but the many binary gems which are difficult or impossible to install on Windows.

The most popular Ruby library for manipulating images (ie. generating thumbnails) is RMagick, but trying to install it on Windows is enough to make a strong man cry. Paperclip is *very* nice for dealing with images and other attachments, but it is also a problem. Then there is a popular JSON parsing library which is also problematic on Windows. Unicorn (a popular Rails server) won't run at all on Windows, and Thin (my favorite) may also give you headaches. And so on, and so on.

You can get pretty far with Rails development on Windows these days, but at times you will find yourself having to test code on a remote server, rather than locally, and it can waste a lot of time.

Comment: The problem is not Rails nor his gems, it's Windows.

Comment: +1 for actually listing gems which are problematic, not just saying Windows is terrible (as many are apt to say). One note though, I have been using Thin on Windows for over a year without any issues. Also, I would recommend using RailsInstaller, which includes DevKit and everything needed for Rails (and yes, RubyInstaller does not currently include DevKit).

Comment: @phoffer, that's very good info: please add it to the answer if you like. I also use Thin on Windows, but at least a couple times, when installing on new dev machines, I've seen the dreaded `mkmf.rb` error message. The problem is installation, not running it once you have it set up right. @Dougui, there's no purpose in pointing fingers; I'm just stating the facts as they are right now.

Comment: @Dougui I did not have that much problems with Django on Windows.

Comment: @WeaponX a lot of things changed since 2012. I think it's easier now. I know you can install Ubuntu on Windows. Maybe it's the simplest option.

Answer (score 4):

Linux, without hesitation. You will find a lot of problems if you want to develop on windows with ruby on rails. I already tried with windows, at my beginning, and it's very difficult. Since I am with Linux, it works!  It's hard in the beginning but it's very powerful.

- Linux is very powerful;
- The majority of the documentation is on a UNIX environment;
- This requires less configuration;
- You will have fewer bugs;
- Every tools are optimized for UNIX systems;

Comment: Rails development has come a long way on a Windows machine. Though, I agree that when I learned Rails a couple years ago on Windows, I spent more time configuring than coding, currently it is a very smooth process from blank slate to fully running Rails environment.

Comment: ...until you get deeper into Rails development and start using gems from different sources. Then you discover the hell-on-earth which is otherwise known as "installing RMagick on Windows". Then you spend nights of agony and tears trying to install `eventmachine`. Then you want to try Unicorn, but discover it is UNIX-only. Then...

Comment: It doesn't help that RMagick hasn't been updated since 2010. =)

Comment: ...Big sigh. I hate to say it, but it's things like RMagick which give open source a bad name. You wouldn't believe some of the crazy bugs I have had to track down in applications using RMagick...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this thread is an old thread but I am here to express how awfully you will encounter problems on windows platform while using Ruby on Rails. It may be 'OK' to build normal application however, as soon as you start scratching the surface of `sqlite3`, `ASCII Characters`, `Internationalisation for an application`, ... Your hair will start to fall off, I mean literally . Whereas if you stick with Mac or Linux (Ubuntu), You will feel invincible, take pride on projects, progress further without having to configure yourself manually with setting of (gems') native extensions library and it is horrendous.

In Summary, to make it work on windows is just nightmare. Whatever you have done it is entirely your decision. I hope everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

It mostly depends on how comfortable you are in each environment. I have been developing on both Windows and Linux for 4 years (because I can't afford a Mac) and I have found Windows to be the easiest in setup, as of late. Engineyard has released an [installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) for Windows that is an all in one for Ruby, Rails, Git, Bundler, SQLite, and DevKit among others.

Windows users are used to simple installers such as that Engineyard provides so if this sounds more like what you are used to, go with that.

Linux provides much more support online for installing Ruby on Rails. There are minor differences with each distro of linux for installing it so I can't provide you with any links. You will also be able to find separate tutorials for installing Git, SQLite, and DevKit.

If you are much more comfortable working in the terminal, than I would suggest taking the plunge into Linux development. It can take a little longer to set up than Windows but you will find it much more command line friendly (and fulfilling).

After you set up Rails, the differences diminish quickly. Development will depend more on what IDE or text editor you are using. Most provide both Linux and Windows versions.

If your focus will be mostly server-side programming then Linux would be the best to look into. If you are working more on client-side, then I would suggest Windows (or MacOS).

My best possible suggestion would be to download VirtualBox, or some other VM, and try Linux. It is free and will only take up a day or so of your time to install and mess around in. If you don't like it, go back to Windows.

(I personally use a combination of both thanks to the miracle that is Bundler)

Answer (score 1):

Linux or Mac. This is because many helpful Gems for Ruby on Rails haven't been ported over to Windows, and never will be (at least, that was the case when I last used Rails). If you do end up doing development on Windows, you may find yourself having to reinvent the wheel many times.

Comment: Which common libraries are those?

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell, unfortunately, the Ruby community is slightly UNIX-biased, and *many* binary gems are easier to install on Linux than Windows. Ruby on Windows is *much* better than it used to be, and the DevKit helps big time (don't *think* of using Ruby on Windows without it), but there are still many gems which can be difficult to install. If someone tried to make a list of those gems, it would go on and on.