# RSpec test pass even when test.log shows ActionNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I follow M Hartl's "Ruby on Rails Tutorial", Chap 3.2.2

When I add /static_pages/about to routes.rb, even the 'about' action is NOT defined in static_pages_controller.rb, the rspec test passes.

It is driving me crazy!

I am using ruby-2.1.1, rspec-rails 2.14.2, Capybara 2.1.0

static_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "StaticPages" do
  describe "About" do
    it "should have the content 'About'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_content('About')
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
RortSampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/about"
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
end
```

command running the rspec test & result:

```
$ rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb 
.

Finished in 0.02604 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 61832
```

And the test.log:

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Started GET "/static_pages/about" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-02 01:59:45 -0700

AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'about' could not be found for       StaticPagesController:
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:131:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
```

Answer (score 0):

In M.Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial book's, 2nd edition's, Gemfile has version 1.1.2 for Capybara. I hope it works better if you change the version of Capybara in your Gemfile.

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
 ...
end
```

Also the rspec-rails gem version was different in the 2nd edition's Gemfile. So if the above change doesn't make it work, then please try the following rspec-rails version: 2.11.0, in addition to the Capybara version change. (I had difficulties with Capybara versions 2.1.0 and 2.2.0)

```
group :development, :test do
..
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
..
end
```

[Gemfile for tutorial's 2nd edition](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/Gemfile)

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't help either. Same result as before.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I got your test working (I should have made proper check in the first place). But after taking a close look I discovered that I used a different Capybara version to make it work: gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'. I had problem with versions 2.1.0 and 2.2.0.

Comment: since capybara 1.1.2 not longer available, I use 1.1.4; but not work. Then I change rspec-rails to 2.11.0, still not work.  And, I also found a weird issue, after I remove the 'about' action from static_pages_controller.rb, and app/view/static_pages/about.html.erb exist, then I can still visit /static_pages/about from a browser !  I AM  USING RUBY 2.1.1, anything wrong ?

Comment: Yes I had version 1.1.4 installed at the beginning because of using gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'. Ruby version 2.1.0. If those RSpec test don't work out in your computer, then you might be better off trying a new rails project (you can copy your files if you want), and use Test::Unit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html If you decide to do that leave Capybara and RSpec gems out from your Gemfile, you dont't need those.

Comment: Btw, are you using Linux, Apple Mac or Windows? -my environment is Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: I am using Mac 10.9.2, I guess I just need to forget about capybara. Even with M Hartl's tutorial's git, after I remove the 'about' action from the controller, the RSPEC still pass !

Comment: hmm... I was thinking if you had Windows, then there could be some possible issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648866/use-windows-or-linux-to-start-work-with-ruby-on-rails. About Mac, I'm not that familiar with Mac but I just discovered there are some issues related Ruby and Mac http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac  If you still can access the about action/page even if you have removed the about from your controller, then it sounds quite strange behaviour indeed from your Rails environment

Comment: Good luck, sorry that I have not been able to assist you that much.