# Deploying Rails 4 in production on windows apache MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, mongrel

We have deployed Rails 4.1.0 / Ruby 2.1.6 on a windows 12 server in development mode with MySQL, using the WeBrick web server. We are now looking to deploy the application to production environment with rails 4.1.0, ruby 2.1.6, windows 12 server, MySQL server 5.6, and apache with Mongrel or XAMPP

Could you point us to the steps / suggestions and ideas to help deploy our rails application to production

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why you are trying to deploy to a windows machine nor why using mongrel / XAMPP. If this is not *really* what you want to do I'd suggest you to go for a classic stack: linux (maybe ubuntu) + mysql (postgres is even better) + passenger. If that's the case I can try to help you, we usually deploy very quickly on Amazon Web Services. Why linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648866/use-windows-or-linux-to-start-work-with-ruby-on-rails.

Comment: we have moved our production environment to Linux(uBuntu)/Nginx/Passenger with MySQL. We are also keen to know about deploying on AWS, if you can provide some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

From experience: the best thing to do is to forget about windows deployment. If this is not an option, then maybe look into JRuby and Warbler. Just don't expect:

- much help from the community (because "nobody" deploys on windows)
- comfortable worfkflow
- stuff that works out of the box

Also i don't see why you would need XAMPP?

Comment: we have done away with XaMPP - that was only a trial among the many we did. Our production is moved to Linux, though development is still running on windows, only to also be replaced to Linux soon

Answer (score 1):

If you are at your first attempts on deploying I'd recommend you [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

### Heroku

The nice benefit is you can install `addons` (eg. a `mysql database`) in a matter of clicks:
- https://elements.heroku.com/

Steps are really easy:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app

Briefly:

```
# Install the `Heroku Toolbelt`
# inside Gemfile: gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# [git init & commit]
$ heroku login
$ apps:create my-app-name # run `heroku create --help` for further help
$ heroku addons:create jawsdb # mysql addon for `heroku`
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

### AWS

After a while you may realize although it's easy to deploy you'll want more tuning and probably better pricing.
At that point usually comes AWS, which has a good balance of all this, I'd recommend you [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elastic-beanstalk/).

- Install [EB CLI 3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html)
- Setup git
- $ eb init
- $ eb use your-environment-name
- $ eb deploy
- $ eb ssh # to enter into the machine

Comment: thanks Adit, very useful to know the steps to deployment on AWS. We have now successfully deployed on Linux